# Debian 10 on HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop with Geforce GTX 1050: Stuck on black screen

Tags: debian, nvidia, amd-graphics, nouveau, graphic-card

I have a HP 15-ec0042ax Pavilion Gaming Laptop with the following hardware:

1.AMD Ryzen 5-3550H

2.GPU 0: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050

3.GPU 1: AMD Radeon Vega 8 Graphics

Windows 10 came pre-installed and works fine.I dual booted Debian 10 along with it.The installation was done smoothly.But I can't reach the login screen and it gets stuck on a black screen with the cursor blinking. I tried to switch off the Nvidia graphics using the following:

nomodeset

nouveau.noaccel=1

noapic noacpi nosplash irqpoll

noapic noacpi irqpoll

nouveau.modeset=0

nvidia-drm.modeset=1

None of these above codes were able to fix it.How do I get this up running?
Thank you in advance.

Edit: I re-installed a non-free version.There was no blank page this time.Instead the command line opened straight away.I went ahead and installed the "nvidia-driver" package using backports.It got installed without any issues.When I rebooted hoping for the GUI, the command line opened instead.So I tried to install the ''nvidia-driver" package again.As expected it said the "nvidia-driver" is the latest version and nothing had to be downloaded.When I run the "nvidia-detect" command, Nvidia GPU is detected and I'm told "Your card is supported by the default drivers.It is recommended to install the nvidia-driver". This OS works perfectly fine on the virtual machine.

Comment: Nope I didn't try this but I'm able to reach the command line and login on the terminal. How do I enable non-free repositories? Also I'm not able to connect to the internet, so I'm not able to install through terminal

Comment: I did try to use the Ethernet but it wasn't detected. Is there anything that I'm missing out on?

Comment: I deleted the previous os and installed an image already with the non free firmware from the link you had posted. But I'm left with the same problem. I'm still stuck at the blank screen. Although I enabled the non free repository I'm not able to connect to the internet.

Comment: I followed the first solution you had suggested.I used Ethernet while installing.So now I'm able to access the internet via terminal.And I've edited the question with what I encountered. I'm still left at the same place.Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Yeah I was confused at why the command line was straight away opening unlike earlier because I installed the complete large installtion with kde environment. That's the reason I had checked for kde-standard. Also task-kde-desktop is installed.

Comment: Do you get the desktop when issuing `startx` on the command line?

Comment: No. I get a bunch of errors like,
xinit: giving up 
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error

Comment: Hello. Do you still have the issue? I see you edited the post, but you might want to move all additional info from the comments to the question to make it easy to understand where are you now. What kernel version do you have? It is still 4.19 in stable. You might want to try installing `linux-image-amd64` from backports considering that [in 4.20 they added "Picasso" firmware support](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux-420-features&num=1), which I suppose Vega 8 in Ryzen 5-3550H uses.